# Python - Geometry Node Image Texture missing image attribute?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, geometry-nodes, image

Successfully pull in images from external location via python by using:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("customimage")
node = mat.node_tree.nodes["customimage"]
image = bpy.data.images.load(dir_path + "/../../" + argv[0], check_existing=False)
node.image = image
```

However, the same node type "Image Texture" available in geometry nodes doesnt appear to be available when browsing thru the data API.

Does anyone know how to change the "image" in the image texture node in a geometry node via python?

[image]

Comment: bpy.ops.image.new() is likely the path you're looking for. Enabling Developer Extras and Pythong Tooltips under Preferences > Interface helps a lot, too.

Answer (score 1):

The *Image Texture* node in geonodes is a little bit more modern because the Image and the frame number can be controlled dynamically through inputs. Therefore you access the image like any other socket value:

```py
image_node.inputs['Image'].default_value = image
```

In your case:

```py
node = bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].nodes['customimage']
image = bpy.data.images.load(dir_path + "/../../" + argv[0], check_existing=False)
node.inputs['Image'].default_value = image
```

Comment: That worked great! Cannot find that anywhere on searches, so thank you!
It works locally but in headless renders the geometry comes out blank. Is there a need to sort of "refresh" the geometry not to get the inputs to regenerate before rendering?

Comment: Nevermind, somehow my timeline got moved to another frame. Sometimes I amaze myself. ;)